# Selected array of div with <a>

Tags: javascript, html, css, electron

I have an understanding or css and html, but I'm quite new to JavaScript...

So, I have a div that has two functions. `(var selection = a[selection].innerHTML;)` is where the problem is, and I'm trying to get `(bread)(milk)(cheese)`

#### My HTML

```js
function PP_BUDGET_CLIENT_TB_ACCOUNT_NUMBER_SEARCHDIV_MOUSEDOWN() {
  //disable div
  var PP_BUDGET_CLIENT_TB_ACCOUNT_NUMBER_SEARCHDIV = document.getElementById('PP_BUDGET_CLIENT_TB_ACCOUNT_NUMBER_SEARCHDIV');
  var a = PP_BUDGET_CLIENT_TB_ACCOUNT_NUMBER_SEARCHDIV.getElementsByTagName("a");
  var selection = a[selection].innerHTML;
  console.log("select = " + selection);

  document.getElementById('PP_BUDGET_CLIENT_TB_ACCOUNT_NUMBER').value = selection;

  PP_BUDGET_CLIENT_TB_ACCOUNT_NUMBER_SEARCHDIV.style.cssText = 'display: none;';
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="CAPTURE_TB" placeholder="ACCOUNT NUMBER" id="PP_BUDGET_CLIENT_TB_ACCOUNT_NUMBER">
<div id="PP_BUDGET_CLIENT_TB_ACCOUNT_NUMBER_SEARCHDIV" class="CAPTURE_SEARCH" style="display:none;">
  <a href="#CHEESE">CHEESE</a>
  <a href="#MILK">MILK</a>
  <a href="#BREAD">BREAD</a>
</div>
```

In the HTML, I'm pulling the page with...

```
<script>
    require('./UniWindow.js')
</script>
```

Inside 'UniWindow.js':

```
//PP_BUDGET_CLIENT_CONTROLLS
var PP_BUDGET_CLIENT_TB_ACCOUNT_NUMBER = document.getElementById('PP_BUDGET_CLIENT_TB_ACCOUNT_NUMBER');
//divs
var PP_BUDGET_CLIENT_TB_ACCOUNT_NUMBER_SEARCHDIV = document.getElementById('PP_BUDGET_CLIENT_TB_ACCOUNT_NUMBER_SEARCHDIV');
//PP_BUDGET_CLIENT_EVENTS
PP_BUDGET_CLIENT_TB_ACCOUNT_NUMBER.addEventListener('keyup', PP_BUDGET_CLIENT_TB_ACCOUNT_NUMBER_ONKEYUP);
PP_BUDGET_CLIENT_TB_ACCOUNT_NUMBER_SEARCHDIV.addEventListener('mousedown', PP_BUDGET_CLIENT_TB_ACCOUNT_NUMBER_SEARCHDIV_MOUSEDOWN)
//PP_BUDGET_CLIENT_FUNCTIONS
```

[image]

so @chrisG suggested

```html
  <input list="browsers" name="browser">
  <datalist id="browsers">
    <option value="Internet Explorer">
    <option value="Firefox">
    <option value="Chrome">
    <option value="Opera">
    <option value="Safari">
  </datalist>
```

but electron does not support this feature. so I have created my own but if anyone could help even if i can somehow pass the variable to the method in the background.

Comment: `java` != `javascript`, that´s one of the first things one should understand :)

Comment: Java is not equals to javascript

Comment: alright thank you. ill update it now

Comment: Update the question n tags accordingly

Comment: where is the function `PP_BUDGET_CLIENT_TB_ACCOUNT_NUMBER_SEARCHDIV_MOUSEDOWN()` being called from?

Comment: i updated the question @NikhilNanjappa

Comment: `var selection = a[selection].innerHTML;` what does this suppose to do? Explain please, it's not a working code line.

Comment: var selection is supposed to be the selected item of <a> either (bread)(milk)(cheese)

Comment: We don't even know what that code is supposed to do... I can somewhat guess, but that's not my job. And you're using a variable called `selection` in the line that declares it. And why use such unwieldy variable names?

Comment: "Selected" how? And what does that _actually_ mean then, what does `selection` contain - a numeric index, or ...?

Comment: @ChrisG the page has alot buttons and text boxes on it i cannot use more than one page. as everything on this page is just for calculation everything else is happening on the main render process

Comment: @CBroe im looking for the value of milk so the word milk to be placed in the text box

Comment: You did not assign a value to `selection`, before you try to use it in `a[selection].innerHTML` - so where is that supposed to come from?

Comment: @CBroe well thats what i cant get, i have tried i can get the length but not the value of what the mouse clicks

Comment: Don't ask about your attempted solution, ask about the original problem. What are you even trying to build?

Comment: @ChrisG what do you mean? this is the orignal problem i cannot get the innerhtml value of the selected item?

Comment: I see that you already added an image explaining the *actual* problem. That's what I meant. Getting an innerHTML value is already part of your fumbled attempt at a solution. Classic http://xyproblem.info/

Comment: correct, and i have searched the web if i run through a for loop i can get it. but i still dont know how to get the selected item.index

Comment: This then? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33985130/create-a-custom-autocomplete-list-for-an-input-field

Comment: Can you just use <select> ?

Comment: @ChrisG ill try it out and respond back if i can get it working

Comment: @maximelian1986 no i cannot use <select> as the values will be dynamically created they have to be searchable per letter not first character

Comment: @ChrisG hi this doesnt work as electron doesnt allow it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create function that assign some variable or just set you div value to text of selection and bind that function to each option onClick.

```
<input type="text" class="CAPTURE_TB" placeholder="ACCOUNT NUMBER" id="PP_BUDGET_CLIENT_TB_ACCOUNT_NUMBER">
    <div id="PP_BUDGET_CLIENT_TB_ACCOUNT_NUMBER_SEARCHDIV" class="CAPTURE_SEARCH" style="display:block;">
       <a name="test" href="#CHEESE" >CHEESE</a>
       <a name="test" href="#MILK" >MILK</a>
       <a name="test" href="#BREAD" >BREAD</a>
    </div>
<script>
   function Choose(){
      document.getElementById('PP_BUDGET_CLIENT_TB_ACCOUNT_NUMBER').value = this.text;
    }
    var elements = document.getElementsByName("test");

    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) 
    {
       elements[i].addEventListener("click", Choose, false);
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, i cannot created the js on the page itself as the values of a have to be created dynamically. which ill do in the background.

Comment: So what a problem? just put <script> content to external js file.

Comment: Thanks bro. there is few things i have to change when i do it in the background but this will work

Answer (score 0):

Possible duplicate of: [setting content between div tags using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8396590/setting-content-between-div-tags-using-javascript)

Try this:

```
document.getElementById('PP_BUDGET_CLIENT_TB_ACCOUNT_NUMBER').innerHTML = selection;
```

Comment: no that will set the value of the text box to selection which is already in the method.. i need to first get the value of one of the <a>